# Issue to preserve binding while styling a checkbox with a template

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, binding, contentpresenter

I've an issue while styling a `CheckBox`. I was inspired by the original `CheckBox` style.

The problem is, I can't find a way to apply the original binding (into the property `IsSelected`). When I remove the style, the binding works. What should I add inside the `ContentPresenter` to preserve the `CheckBox` binding?

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBoxStyle}" MinWidth="6">
```

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
            <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
               <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                  <Border   x:Name="Border"  
                            Width="13" 
                            Height="13" 
                            CornerRadius="0" 
                            Background="White"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource Blue}">
                     <Path Width="8" Height="8" 
                           x:Name="CheckMark"
                           SnapsToDevicePixels="False" 
                           Stroke="White"
                           StrokeThickness="2"
                           Data="M 0 3.5 L 3.5 7 M 3.5 7 L 8 0" />
                  </Border>
               </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
               <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,0,0"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
            </BulletDecorator>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                  <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                  <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Blue}" />
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                  <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Data" Value="M 0 7 L 7 0" />
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                  <!--<Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkGray}" />-->
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                  <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                  <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource LightGray}" />
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer, I already tested that,

I solved my problem just by adding UpdateSourceTrigger property :

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                        ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBoxStyle}" 
                        MinWidth="6">
```

Answer (score 0):

A data grid column always has two styles, the non-editable `ElementStyle` and the `EditingElementStyle`. You only create a style for the non-editable mode, where the `CheckBox` toggle state **must not be changed**.

Since your style allows the `CheckBox` to get focused and participate in hit testing, the edit mode is never entered and the changed toggle state is not applied to the `IsSelected` property.

In order to solve this issue, create a separate style for the non-editing mode based on your `CheckBox` style. This style prevents the toggle state to be changed and instead activates the edit mode.

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCheckBoxElementStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBoxStyle}">
   <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
   <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
</Style>
```

Apply both styles in your column as `ElementStyle` and `EditingElementStyle`.

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected}"
                        ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBoxElementStyle}"
                        EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBoxStyle}"
                        MinWidth="6"/>
```